# Performance of adaptive filter

Tags: filters, adaptive-filters

I have designed an adaptive filter for noise cancellation. Is there any standard way of testing adaptive filters?

Answer (score 1):

It is usually evaluated using the Mean Square Error:

$$ e(n) = \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}(d_{i}(n) - y_{i}(n))^2}{N} $$

Where $ d(n) $ are the values of the samples used to train your filter, and $ y(n) $ are the samples of the filter output. So, you train your filter a number of times $ N $, so as to, for each iteration $ n $ of the training, you have $ N $ values. Than you just compute the equation above, the mean of the $ i $ realizations of training, and plot the error $ e $ by the iteration $ n $.

Comment: boy, i think for this answer to be meaningful, the terms given need more definition.  so $d[n]$ is defined, what's the meaning of the subscript $i$?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will add this information, although it seems obvious.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson: I guess index-i stands for the number of test being performed and identifies signals corresponding to i-th test. He runs the filter N times each with a differet random input sigal x[n] then performs equivalently an ensamble averaging among those N signals obtained by subtracting each complete output y[.] from d[.], sample by sample.

Comment: @Fat32 That's it. You explained better than me. Thanks.